# Removing "\n" at the beginning of each row in a csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a CSV File containing data scraped from amazon reviews. I wanted to do some sentiment analysis on the same in python and would want to remove the "\n" in the beginning and end of each review.
Please guide me on how to do it

P.S: I am a beginner in Python

For example one such row in the file is as follows:

```
['\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n  \n  \n    ', '\n  Actually asusual best phone by redmi.Amazing phone design with best quality camera. Very excellent built quality. It comes with 33w fast charging which is really fast.', 'But I wish it would have 90hz refresh rate.\n', '\n  \n']
```

I want to remove all such \n from each row in the file

Comment: Given that list, what is the desired result?

Comment: The desired output would be: 
Actually asusual best phone by redmi.Amazing phone design with best quality camera. Very excellent built quality. It comes with 33w fast charging which is really fast.', 'But I wish it would have 90hz refresh rate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = ['\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n \n ', '\n Actually asusual best phone by redmi.Amazing phone design with best quality camera. Very excellent built quality. It comes with 33w fast charging which is really fast.', 'But I wish it would have 90hz refresh rate.\n', '\n \n']

print("".join(i.strip() for i in l))
```

Output:

```
Actually asusual best phone by redmi.Amazing phone design with best quality camera. Very excellent built quality. It comes with 33w fast charging which is really fast.But I wish it would have 90hz refresh rate.
```